# spring batch its always gets retried immediately when exception, though retry configuration is not specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have the below chuck step configuration. One of the processor is REST API POST call. so I dont want to retry if there is any exception. But even after I remove the retry configuration, it still retries immediately once from the reader step for the failed item.  What could be missing here? Thank you.

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("chunkStep")
                .<File, CoopReqDTO>chunk(1)
                .reader(filesReader)
                .processor(processor())
                .faultTolerant()
                //.retry(Exception.class)
                //.retryLimit(1)
                .skip(Exception.class).skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .listener(pdfCaptureSkipListener)
                .writer(compositeItemWriter())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FaultTolerantStepBuilder#noRetry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#noRetry-java.lang.Class-) to exclude any exception and (its subclasses) from the retry. You might also check [FaultTolerantStepBuilder#processorNonTransactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#processorNonTransactional--) if you want to cache processing results (this might be useful in your case to avoid re-doing a POST request).

Comment: Thank you. I will check and try today. but I tried something like this - .faultTolerant()
                .noRetry(Exception.class).retryLimit(0) - but it still retried for the error

Comment: After using  FaultTolerantStepBuilder#processorNonTransactional, The REST POST processor is not invoked again when there is a writer failure, But When error is thrown from one of the processor,  Its not getting retried for that item. it directly goes to skiplistener. what might be the issue for it ?

Comment: The retry for processor works when I give this way  - .faultTolerant().retryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy()).   but when I give like - faultTolerant().retry(Exception.class).retryLimit(1) - the retry is not working for processor.

Comment: With retryLimit more than 1, it works.

Comment: with just retrylimit(1), it doesnt retry once